# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null. in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to pass the response to grid values of arraylist.

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final imageModel = imageModelFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

ImageModel imageModelFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return ImageModel.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String imageModelToJson(ImageModel data) {
  final dyn = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class ImageModel {
  int status;
  List<Datum> data;
  int totalRecord;

  ImageModel({
    this.status,
    this.data,
    this.totalRecord,
  });


  factory ImageModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new ImageModel(
    status: json["status"],
    data: new List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    totalRecord: json["totalRecord"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "status": status,
    "data": new List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    "totalRecord": totalRecord,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return '$status $data $totalRecord';
  }
}

class Datum {
  String id;
  String name;
  String thumbnailUrl;
  int plays;
  String categories;
  String categoriesIds;
  String dataUrl;
  int duration;
  String createdAt;
  int status;
  int statusc;
  int mediaType;

  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.thumbnailUrl,
    this.plays,
    this.categories,
    this.categoriesIds,
    this.dataUrl,
    this.duration,
    this.createdAt,
    this.status,
    this.statusc,
    this.mediaType,
  });

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new Datum(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    name: json["name"] == null ? null : json["name"],
    thumbnailUrl: json["thumbnailUrl"] == null ? null : json["thumbnailUrl"],
    plays: json["plays"] == null ? null : json["plays"],
    categories: json["categories"] == null ? null : json["categories"],
    categoriesIds: json["categoriesIds"] == null ? null : json["categoriesIds"],
    dataUrl: json["dataUrl"] == null ? null : json["dataUrl"],
    duration: json["duration"] == null ? null : json["duration"],
    createdAt: json["createdAt"] == null ? null : json["createdAt"],
    status: json["status"] == null ? null : json["status"],
    statusc: json["statusc"] == null ? null : json["statusc"],
    mediaType: json["mediaType"] == null ? null : json["mediaType"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "name": name == null ? null : name,
    "thumbnailUrl": thumbnailUrl == null ? null : thumbnailUrl,
    "plays": plays == null ? null : plays,
    "categories": categories == null ? null : categories,
    "categoriesIds": categoriesIds == null ? null : categoriesIds,
    "dataUrl": dataUrl == null ? null : dataUrl,
    "duration": duration == null ? null : duration,
    "createdAt": createdAt == null ? null : createdAt,
    "status": status == null ? null : status,
    "statusc": statusc == null ? null : statusc,
    "mediaType": mediaType == null ? null : mediaType,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    // TODO: implement toString
    return '$id $name $thumbnailUrl $plays $categories $categoriesIds $dataUrl $duration';
  }
}
```

This is my Imagelist class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:ottdemo_flutter/image_model.dart';


class ImageList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ImageModel>images;
  ImageModel data = new ImageModel();
  ImageList(this.images);

  Widget build(context){
    return GridView.builder(
      itemCount:images.length,
      itemBuilder: (context,int index){
        return buildImage(images[index]);
      }, gridDelegate: null,
    );
  }

  Widget buildImage(ImageModel image) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            //child:Image.network(image.data.toList(growable:true)),
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                bottom:10.0
            ),
          ),
         // Text(image.thumbnailUrl),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

This is my main method call from new class.

```
if(res.statusCode == 200){
      print(mediaResponse);
      if(mediaResponse.status == 1){
      final imageModel =json.decode(res.body);
      var imageData = imageModel['data'] as List;
      for(var model in imageData){
        setState(() {
          images.add(new ImageModel.fromJson(model));
        });
      }
      print("List Size: ${images.length}");
      }
```

Now I am getting an error NoSuchMethodError. For me response is showing properly, but I don't know while I am parsing the thumbnail urls showing error like that. Please check my code and try to help me.

Error:

```
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => Datum)
E/flutter (14235): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core/runtime/libobject_patch.dart:50:5)
E/flutter (14235): #1      new ImageModel.fromJson (package:ottdemo_flutter/image_model.dart:31:45)
E/flutter (14235): #2      _MainActivityGridState.fetchImage.<anonymous closure> (package:ottdemo_flutter/mainactivity.dart:59:26)
```

Error is showing in this line.

images.add(new **ImageModel.fromJson**(model));

Comment: Hello, Mounika. Do know in which line the error is happening? This error means you're trying to call a method on some variable that has a null value (maybe returned, maybe not initialized). Maybe you could edit your question and add the first few lines of the error output.

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Please debug your app and check if `images` is `null` in the line `images.add(new ImageModel.fromJson(model));`

Answer (score 0):

If you arrive here it means you have the same problem, despite of the original question is more than 2yo. Have you seen the question about the Null Security Checking? Google it and report for us if solved you problem and how it was used. It can help others ahead.